# Spark Streaming not detecting new HDFS files

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am running the program below on Spark 1.3.1.  Spark Streaming is watching a directory in HDFS for new files and should process them as they come in.  I have read that the best way to do this is to move the files from an existing HDFS location so that the operation is atomic.

I start my streaming job, I add a bunch of small files to a random HDFS directory, then I move these files from the original HDFS directory to the watched HDFS directory (all with simple shell commands).   But my streaming job is not recognizing these as new files and therefore not processing them.

Currently I am using `textFileStream` but am open to using `fileStream`.  However I am getting errors with this `val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("hdfs:///name/spark-streaming/data/", (p: Path)=>true, false)`

```
package com.com.spark.prototype

import java.io.FileInputStream
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import com.twitter.algebird.HyperLogLogMonoid
import org.apache.hadoop.io._


object HLLStreamingHDFSTest {

  def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/hadoop/spark/conf:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emr/*:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emrfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
    ssc.checkpoint("/name/spark-streaming/checkpointing")

    val lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs:///name/spark-streaming/data/")

    val hll = new HyperLogLogMonoid(15)
    var globalHll = hll.zero
    val users = lines.map(_.toString().toCharArray.map(_.toByte))

    val approxUsers = users.mapPartitions(ids => {
      ids.map(id => hll(id))
    }).reduce(_ + _)

    approxUsers.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (rdd.count() != 0) {
        val partial = rdd.first()
        globalHll += partial

        println()
        println()
        println("Estimated distinct users this batch: %d".format(partial.estimatedSize.toInt))
        println("Estimated distinct users this batch: %d".format(globalHll.estimatedSize.toInt))
        println()
        println("Approx distinct users this batch: %s".format(partial.approximateSize.toString))
        println("Approx distinct users overall: %s".format(globalHll.approximateSize.toString))
      }
    })

    ssc
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate("hdfs:///name/spark-streaming/checkpointing", functionToCreateContext _)

    context.start()
    context.awaitTermination()

  }

}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you fixed the problem of nondection of new files in HDFS (moved from HDFS) ? I have the same problem !!

Comment: can you please try by decreasing your time interval.